# Excel - SUM by IF - Searching for a better technique

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating a simple base spreadsheet for creating a roster / overview of hours for staff (for a period of a fortnight). I want to have a field that when enters 'Sick' then grab the hours to the left of it and add it up.

I have started with something that works:

```
=IF(G6="Sick",F6)+IF(M6="Sick",L6)
```

But it's clumsy and there has to be a better way.

[image]

---

One other note. As optional side note, would love to learn how to conditional format the background colour of the 4 cells to the left of the word 'Sick', if indeed it does appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about a "better" way, as things that work are usually OK, but, unless there will be other instances of "Sick" in the row that should be ignored, you could use something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N($B6:$R6="Sick"),$A6:$Q6)
```

Note that the two arrays are the same length, but offset from each other by one column.  The `N` function turns the array of `TRUE/FALSE` into `1/0`

For your second question, read Microsoft HELP for Conditional Format

**Edit:**  If you must restrict your checking for "Sick" to columns `G,M,etc` then you can use this slightly more complex:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(MOD(COLUMN($B6:$AR6),6)=1),N($B6:$AR6="Sick"),$A6:$AQ6)
```

Comment: Thanks @ron, I agree if it works, it works, but when you have to make a million fields, it can be a bit repetitive. It's not a long term solution to the rostering doing this in excel but for now it works. Cheers for your input. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Brandrally Hopefully you won't have a million fields.  If you do, a different solution might be better.  I've edited my response to restrict checking for "Sick" to certain columns.